# spring-integration-aws S3StreamingMessageSource how do I delete the remotefile?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

i currently work with the S3StreamingMessageSource from spring integration aws. I pass the stream on to an integration flow.

```
public MessageSource<InputStream> s3InboundStreamingMessageSource() {
    S3StreamingMessageSource messageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(template());
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(bucketName);
    messageSource.setFilter(new S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
            "streaming"));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow s3IntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(), spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .transform(new S3ObjectInputStreamToStringTransformer())
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8099/create").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).extractPayload(true))
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
}
```

How can I delete the retrieved remote file from S3?

In the S3InboundFileSynchronizer there is a method for this.

Like this:

```
    @Bean
public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(factory);
    synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(bucketName);
    return synchronizer;
}
```

Can anyone help me or tell me a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We the streaming channel adapter there is no local copy of the remote file therefore we can't guess what and how you are going to do with the `InputStream` for the remote file. So, that's the reason why there is no `setDeleteRemoteFiles()` on the `S3StreamingMessageSource`.

I see you do something like this `S3ObjectInputStreamToStringTransformer`. Tell me, please, what is the reason for this custom transformer. There is already a `StreamTransformer` and with its `charset` option the `InputStream` for remote file is going to be  converted to string:

```
/**
 * Construct an instance with the charset to convert the stream to a
 * String; if null a {@code byte[]} will be produced instead.
 * @param charset the charset.
 */
public StreamTransformer(String charset) {
```

Also: need to keep in mind that `StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getCloseableResource(message)` must be closed after reading an `InputStream` to avoid resource leaking.

Probably instead of `.channel("nullChannel")` you should consider to use a `handle()` for calling an `AmazonS3.deleteObject(String bucketName, String key)` API. The `bucketName` is stored in the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY` and `key` in the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE` headers respectively.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot. Your suggestions have worked.